# CSS Inline Flow Arrows

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create inline flow arrows similar to the attached image:

[image]

I have managed to create something using css, however what I need is for each arrow to contain text and everything falls apart when you try and add text into the center div, and I can't help thinking that there must be an easier way to achieve this.

https://jsfiddle.net/ez8632f4/

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
    <div id="zz" class="arrow-left"></div>
    <div id="zz" class="arrow-ctr"></div>
    <div id="zz" class="arrow-right"></div>
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block;position:relative;left:-30px">
    <div id="zz" class="arrow-left"></div>
    <div id="zz" class="arrow-ctr"></div>
    <div id="zz" class="arrow-right"></div>
</div>

.arrow-left {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 40px solid red;
    border-bottom: 40px solid red;
    border-left: 40px solid transparent;
}

.arrow-ctr {
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
    background:red;
    min-height:80px;
    position:relative;
    left: -4px;
}
.arrow-right {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    border-left: 40px solid red;
    position:relative;
    left: -8px;
}
```

My intention is to eventually animate the arrows flying them in from the right.

Answer (score 3):

You may add **float: left** to the elements:

**CSS:**

```
.arrow-container > div {
    float: left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="display:inline-block;position:relative;left:-30px" class="arrow-container">
    <div id="zz" class="arrow-left"></div>
    <div id="zz" class="arrow-ctr">asdasdasdasd </div>
    <div id="zz" class="arrow-right"></div>
</div>
```

You can change also **.arrow-ctr** to center the text like so:

```
.arrow-ctr {
    display: inline-block;
    width:150px;
    background:red;
    min-height:80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9ay6L0bu/